# How to shorted the middle field of text without losing the other fields

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

Sorry if this has already been covered. I failed to find anything that fit.

If I have a text file with fields of variable length, how can I truncate one field without sacrificing the other fields? An example;

```
firstField secondfieldisthislong thirdField
firstField secondfieldisreallylongandgoesonforever thirdField
firstField secondshortfield thirdField
```

I'd like to truncate the second field to a fixed length. Cut doesn't seem to be able to do this, and my awk/sed skill aren't great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{$2 = substr($2, 1, 10)}; 1' file.txt
```

replace `10` with the length of characters you want.

here we are rebuilding the record(s) with the second field truncated to desired length.

`substr($2, offset, length)` will do string slicing, starting from `offset` upto `length` characters.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                              
firstField secondfieldisthislong thirdField
firstField secondfieldisreallylongandgoesonforever thirdField
firstField secondshortfield thirdField

% awk '{$2 = substr($2, 1, 6)}; 1' file.txt
firstField second thirdField
firstField second thirdField
firstField second thirdField

% awk '{$2 = substr($2, 1, 10)}; 1' file.txt
firstField secondfiel thirdField
firstField secondfiel thirdField
firstField secondshor thirdField
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.* .{6}).* /\1 /' <<< "firstField secondfieldisreallylongandgoesonforever thirdField"
firstField second thirdField
```